# Windows 7 Application to change network settings based on wireless network

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking

I have a laptop that needs different static IP settings based upon the wireless network it attaches to. Windows 7 allows you to set up an alternate settings, but that will only work when DHCP is disabled on the network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have clients that use [Mobile Net Switch](http://mobilenetswitch.com/) due to the requirement of having to travel and connect to different networks within the same division that are not directly connected. They seem to like it and the software will allow you to setup network profiles that will allow you to specify a multitude of settings as can be seen [here](http://mobilenetswitch.com/Screenshots/). It supports 32 or 64 bit versions of Windows 7. It's not a free solution ($29.00 US) but it seems like it would meet your needs.